# Windows 11 cannot access router's USB storage

Tags: windows-11, smbclient

I have two Asus routers, one in *router* mode (192.168.0.1), the other in *AP* mode (192.168.0.2). Both have external HDDs connected through USB & shared through SMB. On my Win10 machine I can access both shares. On my Win11 machine I cannot access the one connected to the AP router (*Windows cannot access \\my-share*)

`arp -a` on Win11 shows both routers' IP, I can access the admin page of both.

`net view` on Win 11 also shows both shares, but this call gives error for the problematic share:

```
C:\Users>net view \\my-share
System error 53 has occurred.
```

Also:

```
C:\Users>ping -a 192.168.0.2

Pinging 192-168-0-2.my_isp_web_address 
...
```

shows this strange address (where *my_isp_web_address* is the domain name of my ISP) instead of the device name as it does for the other router and devices.

What is going on?

**UPDATE:** here's a screenshot of the router's settings, I access this share from FileExplorer like this:

```
\\MY-SHARE\SharedFolder
```

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted the router yet?

Comment: Yeah, to no avail. 3 different win10 laptops (Msi, Asus, Lenovo) connects without any issues, also my phone can connect to that share.

Comment: What models are the routers?

Comment: Main: RT-N18U
AP: RT-AX56U

Comment: It looks like error 53 is usually DNS-related, which would also explain why you're getting a response from your ISP's domain. Are you using IP to connect to the share or does your router have a host name? Usually your share path would look like `\\hostname\sharename` instead of just `\\sharename` . Do an `ipconfig /all` and look for differences in the DNS Servers and DNS Suffix settings between the PCs?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, in the example above `\\my-share` is the "hostname" set in the sharing settings in the router. It's different from the routers' name/devicename, but I access that network share like this: `\\my-share\SharedFolder` . The `ipconfig /all` is mainly the same.

Comment: Do you get the right IP from `nslookup my-share`? Is your main router the DNS server for both PCs? Try and access the share by IP directly via `\\192.168.0.2\SharedFolder`, and see if bypassing name resolution helps. The `net view` command only uses netbios instead of DNS. If both routers are running DNS, make sure they both have a DNS entry for each other's `sharename`

Answer (score 0):

Windows has been disabling older versions of SMB for security reasons. You might need to change the SMB version of the server, or to [enable older versions of SMB in Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3?tabs=server).

- In the Windows 11 *Programs and Features* Control Panel (CPL), select *Turn Windows feature on or off*, if needed.
- In the *Turn Windows feature on or off* CPL, turn on SMB 1.0/CIFS.
- Enable SMB v. 1.0, *if needed* in CMD prompt with

  `sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/mrxsmb20/nsi`

  `sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= auto`
- Enable SMB v. 2.0  *and 3.0* in CMD prompt with

  `sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/mrxsmb20/nsi`

  `sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= auto`

Comment: I forgot to mention: this is enabled on both machines, otherwise I cannot connect to the main router's network share either.